# How to programmatically send List of commands (with parenthesis) from Java to linux terminal? Crontab schedulation related

Tags: java, cmd, cron

I am having trouble sending a list of commands from Java to CMD.
My goal is to programmatically update Crontab schedulation script from Java.

I feel like the issue occurs because the ";" symbol after "-l" in the sent string acts as the command delimiter in CMD. I've tried using both the string directly, and using a process builder (with different combinations, even by splitting the command for each space):

```
String cmd = "(crontab -l; echo '9 * * * * sudo python /home/pi/Desktop/led.py') | sort - | crontab -";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

String commandArray[] = {"(crontab", "-l,", "\"echo '9 * * * * sudo python /home/pi/Desktop/led.py\")", "|", "sort", "-", "|", "crontab", "-"}
Process p = new ProcessBuilder (commandArray).redirectErrorStream(true).start();
```

On both occasions I get the following:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "(crontab": error=2, No such file or directory
```

However, when running the command stored in String cmd directly in terminal, it works fine.
Is there a way to make the console treat the input Runtime string as List of commands through subshell like [HERE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26063/how-are-parentheses-interpreted-at-the-command-line)?
Thank you.

Comment: It seems bash/sh script, so you can choose /bin/bash or /bin/sh as your command then pass these as arguments

Comment: Hi Ahmet, could you please give an example?

On a side note, I managed to get it running meanwhile by storing the crontab commands in a .txt file and then running "crontab -" on:

cat /home/pi/Desktop/Automation/schedule_commands.txt | crontab -

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the issue to the commands being read wrong was fixed by Ahmet's advice in comment to try to run it as a bash script. 
It seems the reason for that is because **Runtime.exec() cannot work with pipes "|".** I've additionally set the command to run crontab from file rather than hard-coding the intended crontab commands and it looks like this:

```
String[] cronString = {
    "/bin/sh",
    "-c",
    "sudo cat /home/pi/Desktop/Automation/schedule_commands.txt  |  crontab -"
    };
System.out.println(cmd3);
Process p3 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cronString);
```

For clarification, schedule_commands.txt contains:

```
0 18 * * * sudo python /home/pi/Desktop/led.py
0 * * * * java -classpath /home/pi/Desktop/Automation automation
```

Comment: Thumbs up Josip.